# Mongodb sum with distinct

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

**Document structure**

```
    {
        "_id": "5a21c5dff772de0555480ef5",
        "date": "2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "amount": 1,
        "location": "Canada",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

I want to count amount for every location and in result have output similar to this:

```
{
  "location": "Canada",
  "amount": 8
}
```

Please give me some hints how to build a aggregate query for this (or maybe there is other way to do that).

Comment: Distinct on which field? Could you provide a better example?

Comment: Distinct on location field and, sum amount field for every location @OmriLuzon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB sum() data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094954/mongodb-sum-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does sound like a job for [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/index.html).

Use the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator to combine your documents by location:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$location", amount: {$sum: "$amount"}])
```

If you absolutely have to have the field be named 'location', use a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to change '_id' to 'location':

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {$group:{_id:"$location", amount: {$sum: "$amount"}}},
     {$project: {location: "$_id", amount:1, _id:0}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Now it's time for me to learn more about aggregation.